# How (preloading) join table on custom column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm

Imagine we have the following models:

```
type Company struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Addresses []Address
}

type Address struct {
    gorm.Model
    CompanyID uint64
    Street string
    City string
    Country string
}
```

I want to take all the companies(and their addresses) which have address in a specific location. Something like this:

```
SELECT company.*, address.* FROM company
INNER JOIN address ON address.company_id = company.id AND address.country = 'Bulgaria'
```

So if a company does not have address at the specific location, I will not get it as a result at all. I was trying something like that:

```
db.Joins("Addresses", "addresses.country = ?", "Bulgaria").Find(&companies)
```

However, it doesn't work, because GORM doesn't take the second argument of Joins(when preloading join used), so I should check the generated query and make something like that:

```
db.Where(`"Address".country = ?`, "Bulgaria").Joins("Addresses").Find(&companies)
```

Is there a better way/not hacky way? Have in mind all of the above code is mock of the real problem, I didn't want to expose the original models/queries.

Comment: Why you are using `LEFT JOIN`? It will give you all the companies.

Comment: @Popeye my bad, edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Preload` to load `Addresses` into the `Company` object.

Based on your described conditions, where you don't want to load companies that don't match your filter, you should use an `INNER JOIN`

**Two options:**

First, if your table is named `company`, then your query should look like this:

```
db.Table("company").
   Preload("Addresses").
   Joins("INNER JOIN addresses a ON a.company_id = company.id").
   Where("a.country = ?", "Bulgaria").
   Find(&companies)
```

Second, if your table is named `companies`, then you should try this:

```
db.Preload("Addresses").
   Joins("INNER JOIN addresses a ON a.company_id = companies.id").
   Where("a.country = ?", "Bulgaria").
   Find(&companies)
```

Comment: Note the table can be named `company` and you can use the second example if you’ve given a `SingularTable: true` NamingStrategy option to `gorm.Open`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gorm v2 you perform CRUD operations on has-one and one-to-many via **associations**:

```
var companies []Company
var addresses []Address
countries := []string{"Bulgaria"}
db.Model(&Address).Where("country IN (?)", countries).Find(&addresses)

// The key is using the previously fetched variable as the model for the association query 
db.Model(&addresses).Association("CompanyID").Find(&companies)
```

This also works for many-to-many relations.

When comparing Gorm VS raw SQL queries (`db.Raw(SQLquery)`) you will typically see a performance hit. On the upside, you will not have to deal with the added complexity of raw sql string building in Go, which is pretty nice. I personally use a combination of both raw and gorm-built queries in my projects :)