# Gorm get all data from table with condition on nested table

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a table with golang struct like this:

```
Order {
  ID
  TransactionID
  Transaction
}

Transaction {
  ID
  ProfileID
  Profile
}

Profile {
  ID
  AccountID
  Account
}
```

How to get all the order with condition of account id with gorm?
I have tried this:

```
 var orders []*Order
 res := r.db.
        Joins("Transaction").
        Preload("Transaction.Profile").
        Where("Transaction.Profile.account_id = 1").
        Find(&orders)
```

But it does not work.

Comment: There are similar questions, please check them out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232715/how-preloading-join-table-on-custom-column/65232939#65232939
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208498/gorm-how-to-joins-preloading-and-user-filter-as-well/70211888#70211888

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should work based on the structs definitions you provided. First, let me show the code and then I'll go through each step:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Order struct {
    Id            int
    TransactionId int
    Transaction   Transaction
}

type Transaction struct {
    Id        int
    ProfileId int
    Profile   Profile
}

type Profile struct {
    Id        int
    AccountId int
    Account   Account
}

type Account struct {
    Id int
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Account{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Profile{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Transaction{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Order{})

    db.Create(&Account{})
    db.Create(&Profile{AccountId: 1})
    db.Create(&Transaction{ProfileId: 1})
    db.Create(&Order{TransactionId: 1})

    // order + transaction + profile + account
    var order Order
    db.Debug().Preload("Transaction.Profile.Account").Joins("inner join transactions t on orders.transaction_id = t.id").Joins("inner join profiles p on p.id = t.profile_id").Joins("inner join accounts a on p.account_id = a.id").First(&order, "a.id = ?", 1)
    fmt.Println(order)
}
```

Let's take a closer look at the code.

##### Structs definitions

Nothing changed here. Be sure to know the GORM conventions when you declare the structs as GORM will create relations, foreign keys, and constraints based on this.

##### Preparing the database

Here, you can find the connection to Postgres, the auto-migrating commands to synchronize the tables, and the insert of some dummy data.

##### The query

Here, we used a lot of methods provided by the GORM package for Go. Let's recap them in a short list:

- `Debug`: it prints to the console the Raw SQL query. It's useful when dealing with complex queries
- `Preload`: loads the related entities but it doesn't include them in the final query produced by Gorm
- `Joins`: it specifies which tables have to be referenced in a JOIN clause. With the `Joins` we add the clause to the query.
- `First`: it's used both for fetching only one record and also for specifying some filter such as in our case (e.g. `a.id = ?`).

Let me know if this clarifies your issue, thanks!